# Issue with fsck on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, mount, drive, fsck

I have an Intel Nuc with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed and all the latest updates.
My NUC randomly crashed and the disk went into read-only mode. I had to force the NUC to shut down and power back on and everything was fine again.

Checking the logs revealed this Warning:
`kernel: FAT-fs (nvme0n1p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`

The **nvme0n1** disk is a Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB and since it is mounted I can't run fsck.
I tried booting into safe mode to run fsck and that wouldn't allow me. I read this is no longer an option in Ubuntu 20. I created a Ubuntu 20.04.2 live USB and booted into there. I was able to see the disk and confirmed it was unmounted. I ran umount just to be sure. Then I tied to run `sudo fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1` and the output said aborting because the disk is in use.

I'm not sure what to do at this point but any insights/suggestions would be very apprecaited!
Thank you!

Comment: Do `sudo swapoff` and/or unmount any swap partitions. You have to `fsck` a partition, not a disk. Use the correct `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1`. Use `sudo fdisk -l` to determine what ext4 partitions you have, and `fsck` those also.

Comment: This worked, I was trying to fsck the disk, not the partition! I also used Fedora Live USB instead of Ubuntu during the second attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

Do `sudo swapoff` and/or unmount any swap partitions. You have to `fsck` a partition, not a disk. Use the correct `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1`. Use `sudo fdisk -l` to determine what ext4 partitions you have, and `fsck` those also.

boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode

- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p1`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: is sudo swapoff essential? I am getting repeated fsck issues. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @katyasehgal See my comment on your question from 4 hours ago.